# Show items of desirialized list in listview

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i am trying to display a desirialized lsit in a listviev with an button. My problem is that everytime I hit that button it adds all saved objects to the list, even if they are already in the list.
Here is my read button:

```
        private async void ReadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder ordner = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile datei = await ordner.GetFileAsync("Kontakt.txt");
        string inhalt = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(datei);
        var k = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<KontakteKlasse>>(inhalt);
        
        foreach (var kt in k)
        {
            kList.Add(kt);
        }
        

    }
```

I also tried myListView.Items.Clear() but that did not help.

Comment: and why didn't you clear `kList` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `Equal` method of the class first:

```cs
public class KontakteKlasse
{
    //Just an example
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is KontakteKlasse klasse &&
               Id == klasse.Id;
    }
}
```

If we don’t want to add duplicates, we need to verify when adding an item, if the item already exists in the data set, it will not be added

```cs
foreach (var kt in k)
{
    if(!kList.Contain(kt))
        kList.Add(kt);
}
```

Thanks.